# Unable to generated pdf file from my asp:button

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I have visited iTextSharp reference i used their sample code to code out one pdf format out. This is the source code of my btnPDF

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPDF" runat="server" Text="Download PDF of Officer's Profile" OnClick="btnPDF_Click" Enabled="false" />
```

When the user selected a gridview data, the btnPDF will change to Enable=true. Therefore when the btnPDF is enable as true, and when the user click the pdf button, it should generate the PDF and run the code after it which i didnt. This is how my btnPDF actually looks like. I'm not very sure is it could be due to the button problem or the generation of pdf's problem.

```
protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Byte[] bytes;

    using (var MS = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        var writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, MS);
        doc.Open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.TotalWidth = 585f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;

        var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/image/logo.jpg"));
        doc.Add(logo);

        var titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 18, Font.BOLD);
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Officer's Profile. Officer's Police ID: " + lblPoliceID.Text, titleFont));

        var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD);
        var phrase = new Phrase();
    }
```

This is what it looks like at the first part of the btnPDF. Behind will show the SQL command to retrieve the different data from the SQL database.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI");

    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select pa.fullname, pp.profilepicture, pp.rank, pa.email, pa.contact, pa.address, pa.postedto, pp.achievement, pp.medal1, pp.medal2, pp.medal3, pp.medal4, pp.medal5 From PoliceAccount pa, PoliceProfile pp Where pa.policeid = '" + lblPoliceID.Text + "' And pa.policeid = pp.policeid", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr;

    dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Full Name :", normalFont));
        phrase.Add(dr[0].ToString());

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Profile Picture :\u00a0", normalFont));
        Byte[] bytes1 = (Byte[])dr[1];
        iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes1);
        image1.ScaleToFit(100f, 250f);
        Chunk imageChunk1 = new Chunk(image1, 0, 0);
        phrase.Add(imageChunk1);

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Rank : ", normalFont));
        Byte[] bytes2 = (Byte[])dr[2];
        iTextSharp.text.Image image2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes2);
        image2.ScaleToFit(40f, 300f);
        Chunk imageChunk2 = new Chunk(image2, 0, 0);
        phrase.Add(imageChunk2);

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Email :", normalFont));
        phrase.Add(dr[3].ToString());

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Contact :", normalFont));
        phrase.Add(dr[4].ToString());

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Address :", normalFont));
        phrase.Add(dr[5].ToString());

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Posted To :", normalFont));
        phrase.Add(dr[6].ToString());

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Achievement :", normalFont));
        phrase.Add(dr[7].ToString());

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Medal1", normalFont));
        Byte[] bytes3 = (Byte[])dr[8];
        iTextSharp.text.Image image3 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes3);
        image3.ScaleToFit(800f, 800f);
        Chunk imageChunk3 = new Chunk(image3, 0, 0);
        phrase.Add(imageChunk3);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Medal2", normalFont));
        Byte[] bytes5 = (Byte[])dr[9];
        iTextSharp.text.Image image5 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes5);
        image5.ScaleToFit(800f, 800f);
        Chunk imageChunk5 = new Chunk(image5, 0, 0);
        phrase.Add(imageChunk5);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Medal3", normalFont));
        Byte[] bytes6 = (Byte[])dr[10];
        iTextSharp.text.Image image6 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes6);
        image6.ScaleToFit(800f, 800f);
        Chunk imageChunk6 = new Chunk(image6, 0, 0);
        phrase.Add(imageChunk6);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Medal4", normalFont));
        Byte[] bytes7 = (Byte[])dr[11];
        iTextSharp.text.Image image7 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes7);
        image7.ScaleToFit(800f, 800f);
        Chunk imageChunk7 = new Chunk(image7, 0, 0);
        phrase.Add(imageChunk7);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Medal5", normalFont));
        Byte[] bytes8 = (Byte[])dr[12];
        iTextSharp.text.Image image8 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes8);
        image8.ScaleToFit(800f, 800f);
        Chunk imageChunk8 = new Chunk(image8, 0, 0);
        phrase.Add(imageChunk8);

        table.AddCell(phrase);
    }

    dr.Close();
    doc.Add(table);
    doc.Close();

    bytes = MS.ToArray();
}
```

In order to allow the browser to prompt a "save as" dialog box when they try to download the PDF file, i have added the content-diposition.

```
Response.Clear();

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

String fileName = "OfficerID " + (String)Session["policeid"];

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");

Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);

Response.End();
```

I've checked and did not manage to find any problem with it. But i do not know why when i click the btnPDF, nothing happened and the codes behind the btnPDF did not run.

Comment: If the click event doesn't fire, the problem is not related to the generation of the pdf. You posted the wrong code.

Comment: I'm not very sure it didnt fire. I tested it out with a label and it works. But after adding the pdf-related code, the click event doesn't seem to fire.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of the click event handler, and run the website. Does the breakpoint get hit when clicking the button?

Comment: Does it work if you set Enabled = "true" on the button?

Answer (score 0):

your code is working properly in my system.
first check your all images path.sometime problem to load images.